# xcode 7. ios 9 sdk. when to free UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a `UIPicker` as inputView for a `UITextField`. I have not created `UIPicker` in storyboard. i declared `UIPickerView` with (retain, nonatomic) attributes. this has ARC enabled by default. so if I alloc the object in `viewDidLoad` when do I release that memory? Am I doing this the correct way?

Thank you.

here is my code:

```
@interface ewfCustInfoViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
:
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *cityPicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *labelCity;
```

in **viewDidLoad:**

```
_cityPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 150)];
_cityPicker.delegate = self;
_cityPicker.dataSource = self;
self.labelCity.inputView = _cityPicker;
```

Comment: Why is `cityPicker` declared as an outlet yet your create it in code? Do one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to release memory in ARC. OS will take care of that.

Comment: if i change attribute to (weak, atomic) I get a warning saying object will be freed after assignment. So I need not do anything if I define it as 'retain'?

Comment: @user3282227 No one said to change the property to `weak`.

Comment: @rmaddy: i first had uipickerview in storyboard and created outlet in storyboard. xcode by default gives it as (weak, atomic). later i removed it from storyboard as i made uipicker as inputView for uitextfield. thats how i still had IBOutlet in there. its gone now.